# Get all Records Using sObject Collections

Tags: rest-api, api, sobject

I see this page:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_sobjects_collections_retrieve_post.htm

but it seems to require a list of record IDs. I want ALL records. is some request available for that purpose?

Comment: Use Bulk API instead. REST API is not suited for large volumes of data. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_intro.htm

Comment: All records of a particular SObject, or _literally all_ of the records for all of your SObjects?

Comment: @DerekF a particular SObject

Comment: @DevelBase2 its less than 2000 records

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to use [the Query resource](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_query.htm) and submit additional requests using the `nextRecordsUrl` if there are more than 2000 results and `done` is `false`.

Comment: someone else in my chat gave the exact same link, so it seems that is the answer. thank you!

Comment: N.B. the `nextRecordsUrl` may appear with fewer than 2000 records, especially if the SELECT fields include `Text area (long` fields with lots of characters in the value(s)